# Install Ubuntu inside/alongside windows 7

Tags: installation, windows-7, partitioning

I'm confused about Ubuntu, last time I installed it, I lost all my Data on hard drive (as I have no experience of Ubuntu). But still I love this operating system as I want some change, the thing I want to know, how can I install Ubuntu so that my all data, partitions and windows 7 wont get effected?

I have Ubuntu 13.04 desktop ISO file. I have made a bootable USB also. I want to install it inside/alongside windows 7, so that i keep learning how to use it and then, maybe migrate to it completely, can you help me on this??

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already made the bootable USB, then change First Boot Device in BIOS to Boot USB.  Once the boot process starts, click on install Ubuntu

[image]

[image]

Once the installation starts, Select install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7. Click continue.

[image]

Make sure that you have the proper drive selected from the drop-down.

The right partition is where Ubuntu is going to be installed. The left partition is the Windows operating system.  Drag the handle bar to re-size the Ubuntu partition. Once you have selected the the size of your Ubuntu partition click install now.